# Nodejs, Moongos find subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this query ( mongoose)

```
user = {email:'my@email.com}; 

return this.company.get().findOne({
            name: companyName,
            users: { $elemMatch: user }
        }).then((res: ICompany) => {
           console.log(res.users);
        }
```

The query is working.
The problem is that I was expecting one user in `res.users` (the one that match the $elemMatch), instead it returns all the users and to select my User I have to do a for-loop over all the users.

Is it possible to modify my query in the way that the `res.users` is populated with the user that match the email?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use of projection, [here the documentation of mongodb 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

```
 return this.company.get().findOne({
        name: companyName,
        users: { $elemMatch: user }
    }, {
      'users.$': 1,
    }).then((res: ICompany) => {
       console.log(res.users);
    });
```

---

[image]